# actionscript tween not running

Tags: actionscript, tween

i've just started actionscript-ing and I encountered problems about tween... Basically, i want my object to fade out in 5 seconds...

here's my code :

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var object:Sprite = new Sprite();
object.graphics.beginFill(0xff00ff);
object.graphics.drawRoundRect(200, 200, 100, 75, 10, 10);

var button:TextField = new TextField();
button.x = 10;
button.y = 10;
button.width = 125;
button.height = 25;
button.text = "Click here to Animate";
button.border = true;

addChild (button);
addChild (object);

button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, animate);

function animate (e : MouseEvent)
{
    var myTween:Tween = new Tween(object, "alpha", None.easeIn, 1, 0, 5, true);
}
```

When i started the movie clip and clicked the textfield, it somehow won't animate...
can anyone point out the mistake??? THX b4...

Answer (score 0):

It is running the tween, you just can't see it. In your animate function change:

```
var myTween:Tween = new Tween(object, "alpha", None.easeIn, 1, 0, 5, true);
```

to

```
var myTween:Tween = new Tween(object, "alpha", None.easeIn, 0, 1, 5, true);
```

And you can see it fires just fine.

**Edit**

As far as making it fade out in 5 seconds it seems to work fine in my tests with your original code, just make sure not to click it again within the 5 seconds or it will reset the tween. Depending on what you are using it for, within your function you can set button.mouseEnabled = false; to prevent additional clicks.

Comment: Put a trace("animate") in your function animate() and see if it is getting the click event

Comment: the trace works, but it still did not animate .....and I didn't clicked it again within the next 5 secs....

Comment: There's probably something simple you are overlooking. It happens to me all the time. Just as a random thing to try, use frames instead of seconds and see if anything changes. `var myTween:Tween = new Tween(object, "alpha", None.easeIn, 1,0, 15, false);`

Comment: still not happening, I've overlooked all my codes and found nothing wrong... what is wrong with this code ???